# Kotlin Firebase Unit Test Mocking await() Never Returns

Tags: firebase, kotlin, unit-testing, async-await

I am trying to write a unit test for code retrieving documents from a Firebase database.  I can't properly mock the database.  Anytime I try to mock (using mockk) the await() function, the code never returns from it.

Here is a portion of the relevant code I'm trying to test:

```
db.collection("some_path_to_documents")
  .get()
  .await()
  .documents
  .forEach { ... }
```

Here's my unit test mocking.  Please forgive the state the code is in.  I've probably modified a couple dozen times by now trying to get it to work.

```
val db = mockk<FirebaseFirestore>()

val querySnapshot = mockk<QuerySnapshot> {
  coEvery { documents } returns mutableListOf<DocumentSnapshot>(deliveryDocument)
}

val querySnapshotTask: Task<QuerySnapshot> = mockk {
  coEvery { await() } returns querySnapshot
}

every { db.collection("some_path_to_documents").get() } returns querySnapshotTask
```

I have breakpoints set for each of the unit test lines and lambdas.  When I debug the unit test, I hit each breakpoint as I would expect until I hit the breakpoint for the await() lambda.  I hit that breakpoint 3 times and after the last time, the code never hits the next (or any) breakpoint.  The call just never seems to return.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?  Or have code for mocking a Firebase database?